# How to avoid page scrolling when scrolling slider with mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, mousewheel

I developed a multiple image slider which is scrollable horizontally with mouse wheel. The problem is that when I scroll down with the mouse wheel on the page and reach the slider, although the slider starts to move from right to left, the page continues to scroll down. I want to prevent the page form further scrolling. I tried to put "overflow: hidden" on the body while the mouse is over the slider, but then the slider jumps because of the scroll disappearing and reappearing. Does anybody have an idea how could I solve this? Thank you in advance.

```
  sliderWrapper.addEventListener('wheel', () => {
           
    let sliderLeft = firstImg.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let sliderWrapperLeft =  sliderWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    let sliderRight = lastImg.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    let sliderWrapperRight =  sliderWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().right;

    function detectMouseWheelDirection(e) {
      var delta = null,
        direction = false;
      if (!e) {
        // if the event is not provided, we get it from the window object
        e = window.event;
      }
      if (e.wheelDelta) {
        // will work in most cases
        delta = e.wheelDelta / 60;
      } else if (e.detail) {
        // fallback for Firefox
        delta = -e.detail / 2;
      }
      if (delta !== null) {
        direction = delta > 0 ? 'up' : 'down';
      }

      return direction;
    }

    function handleMouseWheelDirection(direction) {
      // if mousewheel direction is down, move the slider to the left
        
       if (direction == 'down' && sliderRight > sliderWrapperRight) {
        innerSlider.style.left = --count * 15 + '%';
        // if mousewheel direction is up, move the slider to the right
      } else if (direction == 'up' && sliderLeft <= sliderWrapperLeft) {
        innerSlider.style.left = ++count * 15 + '%';
      } else {
        innerSlider.style.left = 0 + '%';
        count = 0;
      }
            
    }

   document.onmousewheel = function (e) {
      if (isMouseHover) {
          handleMouseWheelDirection(detectMouseWheelDirection(e));
      }
    };

    if (window.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        handleMouseWheelDirection(detectMouseWheelDirection(e));
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: To start with, defining functions inside an event handler (i.e. inside your `"wheel"` event callback function) is a really bad idea, a coding antipattern. Define reusable functions outside, in the root or module scope, and use them (call) where needed.

Comment: Don't use the CSS `left` property to move elements around. Instead use CSS `translate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prevent the default behavior of the event and it's propagation in your sliderWrapper event listener for the wheel: pass it as a parameter for the listener function, and then

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: What if OP on that page has other (owned or 3rd-party) scripts, really important scripts listening for `"wheel"` (without the capture phase)? Your `e.stopPropagation()` would make other scripts and potentially the entire UI fail. Also your answer is not complete given OP's code is flawed by design.

Comment: That's a good point! Would you kindly give us any advice on how to achieve what OP needs?

Comment: Thank you, e.preventDefault(); solves the problem. That's pretty basic, I could have thought of it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help!